# How to access id from this httpresponse in angular to perform edit and delete actions based on id

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

[In the screenshot showing list of applications created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85sQR.jpg)

function to get list of apps -> ts file

```
 getcmsApps() {
    this.getCmsService.getApps().subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.data = res;
      console.log(res)
    })
  }
  editAppById(appid: string): void {

  }
  deleteAppId(appid: string){

  }
```

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?  According to the image, it appears that `this.dataCopy` will be set to an array of objects, and each of those objects will have an `id` property.  Where are you trying to use that data and how did that attempt fail?

Comment: Sorry i missed to remove that datacopy line.  So need to pass id which i'm getting in the http response to perform edit and delete actions.

Comment: You're essentially asking this community to do all of your work for you.  Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/328193)  You are encouraged to make an attempt.  If during your attempt you encounter a specific problem, such as a specific operation producing an error or an unexpected result, we can help with that.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response you get is an object array. So you can just loop trough the array and access the field by its key name

```js
let AngularResponse = [
{
  createdon: "4/1/2022",
  division: "test",
  email: "aaaa@gmail.com",
  fax: "1",
  hrbinformation: "1",
  id: "d7ab1fc0-0e33-4fb7-ac71-1bf48ddd8bf8"
},
{
  createdon: "6/2/2022",
  division: "test",
  email: "bbbbbb@gmail.com",
  fax: "2",
  hrbinformation: "2",
  id: "a869fdd8-bf99-49d9-bb72-7bb11e6fadbf"
},
]

console.log(AngularResponse[0].id);

//OR to get all of them

AngularResponse.forEach(arrayItem => console.log(arrayItem.id))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Usually the httpService will return an Observable on which you can subscribe in the subscription part you can perform all sorts of operations based on the response you got.

I have to take a look at you code to give you further informations but what I can suggest to do is the following

```
request = // your http request observable from httpService 
request.subscribe((response) => {
   // retrieve the id from the response object (as I can see in the 
   // screenshot your response is an array so you will probably have to loop 
   // through it)    
});
```

Another option to consider would be to use RxJs operators to make operations on the response object (eventually using the *tap* operator) before the subscription part.